# Multiple definitions of friend operator in templated class

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, argument-dependent-lookup

I have the following code snippet:

```
template < typename T1, typename T2 >
class Test
{
  public:
    Test() = default;

  private:    
    template < typename T1_, typename T2_ >
    friend Test< T1_, T2_ > operator*( const Test< T1_, T2_ >& lhs, const Test< T1_, T2_ >& rhs )
    {
        return Test< T1_, T2_ >();
    }
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    {
        Test< int, int > t1;
        Test< int, int > t2;
        Test< int, int > t3 = t1 * t2;
    }

    {
        Test< double, double > t1;
        Test< double, double > t2;
        Test< double, double > t3 = t1 * t2;
    }
}
```

With clang 3.9 the code compiles fine, with gcc 6.3.1 I get the following error:

```
redefinition of ‘template<class T1_, class T2_> Test<T1_, T2_> operator*(const Test<T1_, T2_>&, const Test<T1_, T2_>&)’
     friend Test< T1_, T2_ > operator*( const Test< T1_, T2_ >& lhs, const Test< T1_, T2_ >& rhs )
```

Which compiler is right?

If it is gcc, which I suspect, how can I correctly declare the templated operator* in-class. In-class definition is necessary for me for argument dependent lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC is correct, as every instantiation of `Test` defines template `operator*`, which are identical as their signatures don't depend on `T1` or `T2`. `operator*` needs not be template here, just an overload for a particular instantiation of `Test`:

```
template < typename T1, typename T2 >
class Test
{
    friend Test operator*(const Test& lhs, const Test& rhs)
    {
        return Test();
    }
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    {
        Test< int, int > t1;
        Test< int, int > t2;
        Test< int, int > t3 = t1 * t2;
    }

    {
        Test< double, double > t1;
        Test< double, double > t2;
        Test< double, double > t3 = t1 * t2;
    }
}
```

This will instead define two non-template overloads of `operator*`, one for each instantiation of `Test`.

Comment: I need the operator templated. However in-class friend declaration and out of class definition solved the compile error. Thank you!

Comment: @Trevir why do you need it to be a template?

Comment: To multiply objects of different type. `Test< int, int > t1, Test< double, double > t2; auto t3 = t1*t2` is valid and should compile.

Comment: @Trevir then you can use in-class overloads that are templated on `rhs` only: `template <typename U1, typename U2> friend Test</* ??? */> operator*(const Test<T1, T2>& lhs, const Test<U1, U2>& rhs)`